# How can I change the currency in the Shopify store?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

How can I change the currency in the **Shopify** store using **liquid** template language?

Comment: you like a way to just show a different currency, change the currency on the store, support multiple currencies?

Answer (score 0):

Generates a drop-down list that customers can use to select an accepted currency on your storefront.

```html
{% form 'currency' %}
  {{ form | currency_selector: class: 'my_special_class', id: 'Submit'  }}
{% endform %}
```